# When to open and close a SQlite DB in the iOS lifecycle?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, memory-management

I run a series of queries throughout the lifecycle of my app.

I am currently using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (An Objective-C wrapper around the Sqlite C API), and I am opening and closing before every query.

```
FMDatabase * db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:pathToMyDB];
[db open]
FMResultSet * s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM myTable"];
// Use FMResultSet
[db close];
```

Open and close trigger `fopen()` and `fclose()` lower down, so I belive I can gain a perforce win by keeping the database open.

However, I believe temporary objects will build up, which could lead to memory issues.  [Closing the database](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html) clears the temporary objects.

- When should I open and close the database connection? (e.g. Application did enter backgound?)
- Should I run [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) in low memory situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database doesn't create and/or keeps any objects (or at least it shouldn't). The C API is just a handy way to use SQL queries but once those are executed they should be released.

Now, for the returning objects of a query, those are just copied into your FMResultSet. Once you release that they're gone.

Imo, if the database itself is not too big, you should keep a reference to it in your app delegate (guarantee to be alive in the lifetime of your app). When you enter the app/resume from background open the database and when you go into background/close just close it.

Keep in mind that AppDelegate is a singleton ( i think) and you can access your database using `(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].your_db` from anywhere in your app to perform the actual queries.

Using VACUUM will crash your app if you try to call it when you get memory warning. Think about this: to rearrange the database it should be loaded into memory (or at least a part of it), if you already have memory warning...poof...crash.

You could test if your database keeps objects in memory. Just perform like 100 queries at 1s interval (or a button press) and watch in instruments where and if the memory grows. You may have a leak in your app ( or in the wrapper itself) and you blame it on the database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Are you 100% sure that database doesn't create and/or keeps any objects?  You are probably right, but, this documentation says: "return SQLITE_OK if the sqlite3 object is successfully destroyed **and all associated resources are deallocated**" http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/close.html

Comment: I think the associated resources refers to the connection itself , and a few other things that you need to access it. As i said, i'm not sure, server databases do this. Then again they don't need to be opened, per se. Do as i said, test it like: in a separate class open database, perform a ridiculous amount of queries ( while watching memory ) and then close it. It should be obvious what's happening. If it keeps some object you'll see that the memory keeps growing till the app crashes, if not everything should remain at a relative constant memory allocation. That's the easiest way to be sure.